# Proving identity element

Tags: field-theory

> Let $a,b$ be two elements in a skew field $F$. If $b\neq 0$ and $(ab)^2=ab^2+bab-b^2$, then prove that $a=1$.

Since $F$ is a skew field so we can write $aba=ab+ba-b$, then what shall I do?

Please give hints.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a\neq 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
aba - ab &= ba - b\\
\implies ab(a - 1) &= b(a - 1).
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here? Bonus question: can you complete the argument *without* making the initial assumption $a\neq 1$?